# NuGet Packages for Cellular Data Internet

Tags: xamarin.forms, cellular-network

What NuGet packages should be installed to enable Xamarin cross-platform mobile devices to use cellular data to access the Internet and reach app services?

Comment: None.  The OS should manage connectivity for you, your app should work over whatever connection is available.  The Essentials Connectivity plugin will allow you to determine which connection is active.

Comment: If I turn off WIFI manually, both Android and iOS versions of my app lose Internet connectivity, so the OS's are not managing connectivity properly. My research indicates that HttpClient might be the necessary module, but that was years ago.

Comment: Have you tried this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/connectivity?tabs=android

Comment: I hadn't, but have now. With WiFi enabled, Essentials shows Internet access but of Unknown type. With WiFi disabled, it shows no Internet access and a Unknown type.


Essentials doesn't have any capacity to establish connectivity, just report on it.

Comment: With a few adjustments, I have Internet with or without WiFi enabled, but Unknown remains the profile type. However, System.Net.NetworkInformation.Ping never returns when reaching out to an address that returns replies using a CMD Ping on the dev system.

Answer (score 0):

Talking it a step forward, I did a simple TCP test to see if a connection was actually possible:

'TcpClient c = new TcpClient("52.173.xx.xxx", 443);'

It was when looking at the TCPClient attributes even though the profile was Unknown.